# Transparently decomposing an ASP.NET Website hosted in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core

I maintain a website written in ASP.NET MVC 5, and hosted in Azure. It's a legacy app that is a real nightmare to maintain, and so I've been asked to start migrating to a new codebase and the ASP.NET Core framework.

Our goals are:

1. Migrate one page at a time
2. Don't lose the "F5 debugging" experience in Visual Studio

My initial thought was to use a virtual application/directory, which is supported both in Azure and in IIS Express. The idea is to point, for example, the `/Shop` page to the new website by using a virtual path. Then when we're ready, move the `/Team` page and so on. I would add a virtual path for each migrated endpoint until the migration is complete.

To accomplish this I created a new ASP.NET Core project, and I've been trying to edit my `applicationhost.config` file and trying to start multiple projects from Visual Studio, without luck.

I tried configuring two `site`s with the same port binding, two apps within a `<site>` tag and also two virtual directories within an `<application>`, but I always end up with errors. Either I can't start debugging (`Can't connect to IIS Express` or `The object invoked has disconnected from its clients` messages) or I get a 502 error.

I don't even know if this is going to work in Azure, but I know we can't go down this path without proper development experience.

Am I missing some other, better solution? If this is a good solution, is there any way to make this work in Visual Studio?

Comment: You need first to understand that you can't port or migrate from ASP.NET MVC 5 to ASP.NET Core. The process is called rewriting. You'll have to rewrite your whole project.

Comment: I do, but thanks for clarifying! I want to create a new project, and then rewrite each page at a time. We can't afford the development cost of doing it all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider creating multiple new websites in Azure, one for each section. Then, as I start working with Shop, for example, I'd leave an almost-empty controller in the original solution, redirecting to your new Sales web site. Using this approach, you can efficiently work with one smaller code base at a time and in the future scale the individual pieces of your site as needed. Please note, that you can host multiple sites within the same app service environment (thus not incurring a lot of extra cost by separating into multiple processes).

Best of luck :-)

Comment: Makes sense! I guess I could use the old controller endpoints as proxy to the new website and just hide this from the client, right? It would be difficult for me to make a case for having two different domains/subdomains.
EDIT: And I'd also have to proxy any request to resources like css and js files stored in the new website, am I right?

Comment: As far as common, static, resources, consider using Azure's CDN functionality. Scott Hanselman has written up a great post on it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingVideoMovingMyWebsitesImagesToTheAzureCDNAndUsingACustomDomain.aspx). When it comes to multiple host names - if the site *is* large enough that it today warrants a rewrite due to being unmaintainable, then that in itself is a good argument for splitting it up. One could argue that the Team site should not be the *same* as the Sales site. But then, it's a call/argument having to be made up with the actual code as proof.

Comment: I'll mark this as resolved as I think this is good advice. Thanks for helping out! I may come back later and give feedback based on how it goes :).